# Drag to sort Text widget list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I'm in the middle of a personal project where I need to have a drag-to-sort-able list of text widgets. I've implemented the same functionality temporarily with a reordablelistview, but the results are too bland and ugly, so I'd like to implement it in the way described above. I have a visual mockup of what I'm trying to achieve, displayed below:

[image: Visual mockup, shows hand dragging item and it getting sorted into place]

In my research, I came across the Draggable / DraggableTarget widgets, but I'm not sure 1- if those are the right approaches, 2- how to implement those. Any guidance in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this dependency to create list like that

```
drag_and_drop_lists: ^0.3.3
```

page link
https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists